# Automapping subclass in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, subclassing

I'm having some trouble getting fluent nhibernate to properly map the class hierarchy that I have.

Presuming that I have the following class structure

```
public abstract class MedicationAction
{
   ... Id and other attributes
   public virtual MedicationStatus MedStatus { get; protected set; }
}

public class CeaseAction : MedicationAction
{
   ... other properties that I want to be auto mapped
}

public class StartAction : MedicationAction
{
   ... other properties that I would like to be auto mapped  
}
```

All of these classes are mapped to the same table, so I'm using a table-per-class-hierarchy strategy.

The auto map override I have look like this:

```
public class MedicationActionMap : IAutoMappingOverride<MedicationAction>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<MedicationAction> mapping)
    {
         mapping.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("MedActionTypeCode");

         mapping.SubClass<CeaseAction>("Cease");
         mapping.SubClass<StartAction>("Start");
    }
```

In my AutoPersistenceModel generation code, I have the following

```
 return AutoMap.AssemblyOf<MedicationAction>()
      .... etc. 
      .Setup(s => 
           {
               ... etc.
               s.SubclassStrategy => SubclassStrategy.Subclass;
           }
```

2 questions:
1. Should I have auto mapping overrides for the StartAction and CeaseAction classes and put the .Subclass methods in there instead of in the MedicationAction auto mapping override, like I have here?
2. In the hbm that results from this auto-mapping, I get the following (excerpt):

```
<class name="MedicationAction">
    ...
    <discriminator type="String">
      <column name="discriminator" />
    </discriminator>
    ...
    <subclass name="CeaseAction" />
    <subclass name="StartAction" />
    ...
 </class>
```

As you can see, the discriminator column and values are being completely ignored.  If I remove the line (s => s.SubclassStrategy = t => SubclassStrategy.Subclass) I get the right discriminator column, but then all of the subclass elements become joined-subclass elements.  How do I get the subclass strategy to actually pick up my discriminator column and values?  I'm using Fluent NHibernate 1.0 RTM.

I know how to get this working using manual mappings, but there is a lot of other information in these classes that is auto mapped, and I want to keep that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have the `SubClass` calls in your override. They will be picked up automatically by the automapping.

Comment: Except that there is then no way to set the discriminator value.

Comment: If you're not happy with the discriminator value being the class name, then you can implement an `ISubclassConvention`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the method AutoMapping<T>.SubClass<TSubClass>()?